# Future Perfect Continuous

Tags: perfect-constructions

Tell me please, if it is okay to use the future PC tense without a time span, like this?:

- "I will have been waiting for him when he finishes with his business."
- "Will you have been working when I arrive?"

Also I was told that such sentences with "before" are weird:

- "Before he leaves for home he will have been working at the conference for two days."
- "Before they go to the competition the coach will have been training them for three months."

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

Your first two sentences are odd.

When 'he' finishes work, the speaker *will be* waiting for him. There is no reason to use the future perfect unless you want to say how long the speaker will have to wait.

Similarly, the second seems an unlikely question to ask. If the speaker expects to find the other person still working when they arrive, they will ask "Will you be working?"

The other two sentences are wrong. 'He' will have been at the conference for two days *when* he leaves, not *before* he leaves. (The two days won't be over until the moment of his departure.)

The coach *will train* the team for three months *before* the competition, OR they *will have been* training for three months *when* they go.

Comment: How wrong do the last two sentences feel to you? To my Canadian ears, they're fine, with "before" meaning something like "by the time".

Comment: Thank you for the answers. By the way, the second sentence is from here "https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verb-tenses_future-perfect-continuous.htm".